# Is it "mobilized to X" or "mobilized into X"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

Is it "mobilized to X" or "mobilized into X"? I am not sure what's the correct idiomatic use of the verb mobilized. I think it's the former, but I am thinking it might actually be wrong, so I am wondering what's the correct way of using it.

For example:

> The military command **mobilized** the amphibian unit to sea in order to
>   attack the enemy by sea.

Comment: *To* (or *at*) would be used if talking about a location, and *Into* if talking about a particular shape or configuration. (In other words, *into a fighting unit* or *into an X type of formation.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mobilized** is not the same as **moved**, even if they sound similar. One just mobilizes something, not "to", not "into".

Therefore I would rewrite your sentence:

> The military command mobilized the amphibian unit <strike>to **the** sea</strike> in order to attack the enemy by sea.

In this way, I also got rid of the ugly repetition of "sea".

Getting rid of the repetition by un-using the other "sea" makes the sentence just awkward:

> The military command mobilized the amphibian unit to **the** sea in order to attack the enemy <strike>by sea</strike>.

Comment: What about: "The military command will mobilize the amphibian unit to sea when the situation requires it."?

Comment: According to the dictionaries, mobilize = prepare. Since you cannot really "prepare to sea", "mobilize to sea" is also not OK, from my POV. However, I am not a typical user of this word / these sentences, so somebody more knowledgeable might want to clarify some things for us.

Comment: +1 Mobilise (Uk english spelling) is more like activating something - changing it's state from standby into action. You could *mobilise the amphibian unit and send it to sea*, but it may be obvious it's going to sea as it's an amphibian unit. I am wondering though whether you could *mobilise the 3rd regiment to Afghanistan* though.